# How many four digit numbers are such that reading from right to left , each digit is greater than the digit at previous position?

Tags: combinatorics

How many four digit numbers are such that reading from right to left , each digit is greater than the digit at previous position?

**My approach:**

We want a 4 digit number of type abcd where a>b>c>d

According to me answer should be 10c4 , as any 4 numbers chosen will have only 1 arrangement in which a>b>c>d, but the answer given in the book is 9c4, please help me identify my mistake

Comment: If the first digit you choose is 0, then you don't actually have a 4-digit number.

Comment: @ConMan That's impossible if the thousands digit is supposed to be the largest digit.

Comment: Right, sorry, I got the > signs the wrong way around. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet.

Comment: Looks to me like your solution is elegant and correct.  I encourage you to include the problem statement in the body of the Question, not just in the title.

Comment: Your answer looks fine to me after I figured out what you meant. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the formulas in your MSE posts. Then you can use notation  like $_{10}C_4$ (if that is what you meant by 10c4) by typing _{10}C_4 in between two dollar signs.

Comment: the books answer is true for $a<b<c<d$ ,but if the question $d<c<b<a$ , then for $abcd$ your answer is correct